# Let $S$ be a nonempty subset of a group $G$. Then Span of $S$ is $\langle S\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S$ be a nonempty subset of a group $G$. Then Span of $S$ is
$$\langle S\rangle \stackrel{?}{=}A=\{s_{1}^{e_1}s_{2}^{e_2}...s_{n}^{e_n}| n\in\mathbb N, e_n=\pm 1\}$$

Logic of the proof is fairly simple as follows. $\langle S\rangle$ is intersection of all subgroup of $G$ and $A\subseteq \langle S\rangle$ is obvious.

$\langle S\rangle\subseteq A$ is true if we can prove $A$ is a subgroup of G.

Lets show: $s=(s_{1}^{f_1}.s_{2}^{f_2}..s_{m}^{f_m}),t=(t_{1}^{g_1}...t_{n}^{g_n})\in A$

Then why should $st^{-1}$ in $A$

$(s_{1}^{f_1}.s_{2}^{f_2}..s_{m}^{f_m})(t_{1}^{g_1}...t_{n}^{g_n})^{-1}=s_{1}^{f_1}.s_{2}^{f_2}..s_{m}^{f_m}t_{n}^{-g_n}t_{n-1}^{-g_{n-1}}...t_{1}^{-g_{1}} \in A$ why?

My problem with $(s_{1}^{f_1}.s_{2}^{f_2}..s_{m}^{f_m})(t_{1}^{g_1}...t_{n}^{g_n})^{-1}=s_{1}^{f_1}.s_{2}^{f_2}..s_{m}^{f_m}t_{n}^{-g_n}t_{n-1}^{-g_{n-1}}...t_{1}^{-g_{1}} $

In $A$ shouldnot be the order conserved? I mean order should $...s_{j}^{f_j}...s_{y}^{f_y}...$

for any index $j>y$

But for example If I take $s_1s_2$, and $s_2s_3s_4$ in A

$(s_1s_2)(s_4^{-1}s_3^{-1}s_2^{-1})$ not neccessary be in A, then why do we say $s_{1}^{f_1}.s_{2}^{f_2}..s_{m}^{f_m}t_{n}^{-g_n}t_{n-1}^{-g_{n-1}}...t_{1}^{-g_{1}}$  is in A

Comment: Why is $s_1s_2s_4^{-1}s_{3}^{-1}s_{2}^{-1}$ not in $A$? The exponents are allowed to be $-1$. The order of the subscripts does not matter either, as long as each $s_k$ is an element of $S$. Intuitively, elements of $A$ are those that are a "product of things that are elements of $S$ or inverses of elements of $S$".

Comment: slightly unrelated, but consider using \$\stackrel{top text}{bottom text}\$ for equations with question marks

Comment: I guess my problem is, there is a S-set and has finite element $s_1,s_2,....,s_n$

And my understanding of set A is a for a fixed order of set S for example as given in this comment above, because of this one cannot satisfy closure. I am little confused.

Comment: Now it is clear, during writing I understand my mistake. Ordering is the problem.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the problem. $A$ is the collection of all "words" which can be made by multiplying a finite number of elements from $S$ and inverses of elements of $S$. Is $s_1^{f_1}...s_m^{f_m}t_n^{-g_n}...t_1^{-g_1}$ such a word? Yes, it is. It is indeed a product of finite number of elements which either belong to $S$ or are inverses of elements of $S$. What does it have to do with the index? The elements have no specific order, it is just a question of how you call these elements.